# Rotate files created by nxlog

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, nxlog

I am using nxlog-ce on Windows Server 2012 R2.

nxlog is outputting two txt files.

I would like to rotate these two files every hour. I want the active log to maintain the same name,  logfileA.txt logfileB.txt and new rotated files to be created logfileA.txt.2 logfileB.txt.2

I only ever want there to be two files for each log logfileA.txt and logfileA.txt.2   but never a logfileA.txt.3

Here are the important parts from my current nxlog.config

```
define LOGFILE_Atxt C:\test\logfileA.txt
define LOGFILE_Btxt C:\test\logfileB.txt 


<Extension fileop>
    Module      xm_fileop
    <Schedule>
        Every 1 hour
        Exec    file_cycle('%LOGFILE_Atxt%', 2);
        Exec    file_cycle('%LOGFILE_Btxt%', 2);
    </Schedule>
</Extension>


<Output loga_out>
    Module      om_file
    file        'c:\test\logfileA.txt'
    CreateDir   TRUE
</Output>   

<Output logb_out>
    Module      om_file
    file        'c:\test\logfileB.txt'
    CreateDir   TRUE
</Output>   

<Route loga_route>
    Path        loga_input => loga_out
</Route>
<Route logb_route>
    Path        logb_input => logb_out
</Route>
```

In this configuration, when the nxlog service starts it immediately creates logfileA.txt.1 and logfileB.txt.1
However, the system never rotates the logs. logfileA.txt.2 and logfileB.txt.2 are never created.

I am having trouble finding resources covering how to setup log rotation with nxlog.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is that om_file keeps writing into the rotated file. You need to notify it so that it will reopen its output. The following should work:

```
<Extension fileop>
    Module      xm_fileop
</Extension>

<Output loga_out>
    Module      om_file
    file        'c:\test\logfileA.txt'
    CreateDir   TRUE
    <Schedule>
        Every 1 hour
        Exec    file_cycle('%LOGFILE_Atxt%', 2);
        Exec    loga_out->reopen();
    </Schedule>
</Output>   

<Output logb_out>
    Module      om_file
    file        'c:\test\logfileB.txt'
    CreateDir   TRUE
    <Schedule>
        Every 1 hour
        Exec    file_cycle('%LOGFILE_Btxt%', 2);
        Exec    logb_out->reopen();
    </Schedule>
</Output>
```